# Is 97 processes on an Apache2 server normal?

Tags: server

I have 97 processing running, that's what top reports.  I only have the base install + apache2 and php5.  Could it really add that much stuff?  Or does the ubuntu-desktop have like 300 processes?

I am running it on an old G4 powerpc.

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 13:35 ?        00:00:01 /sbin/init
root         2     0  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root         3     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         4     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/0]
root         5     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [events/0]
root         6     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [cpuset]
root         7     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [khelper]
root         8     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [netns]
root         9     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [async/mgr]
root        10     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [pm]
root        11     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [sync_supers]
root        12     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [bdi-default]
root        13     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [kintegrityd/0]
root        14     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [kblockd/0]
root        15     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [ata/0]
root        16     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [ata_aux]
root        17     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [ksuspend_usbd]
root        18     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [khubd]
root        19     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [kseriod]
root        21     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [khungtaskd]
root        22     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [kswapd0]
root        23     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [ksmd]
root        24     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [aio/0]
root        25     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [crypto/0]
root        28     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [khvcd]
root        30     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [kondemand/0]
root        31     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [kconservative/0]
root       196     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [khpsbpkt]
root       197     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [usbhid_resumer]
root       199     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [knodemgrd_0]
root       200     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [jbd2/hda3-8]
root       201     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root       262     1  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
root       266     1  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 udevd --daemon
root       278     2  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 [kapmd]
syslog     579     1  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 rsyslogd -c4
104        586     1  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon --system --fork
root       641     1  0 13:35 tty4     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
root       645     1  0 13:35 tty5     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty5
root       649     1  0 13:35 tty2     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
root       650     1  0 13:35 tty3     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
root       653     1  0 13:35 tty6     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
daemon     669     1  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 atd
root       670     1  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 cron
bind       717     1  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/named -u bind
mysql      761     1  0 13:35 ?        00:00:03 /usr/sbin/mysqld
root       774     1  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mouseemu
root       776   774  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mouseemu
nobody     830     1  0 13:35 ?        00:00:00 dnsmasq --strict-order --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/libvirt/network/default.pid --conf-file=  --listen-address 192.168.122.1 --except-interface lo --dhcp-range 192.168.122.2,192.168.122.254 --dhcp-lease-max=253
root       880     1  0 13:35 tty1     00:00:00 /bin/login --     
root      1899     1  0 13:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon
alex      1971   880  0 13:36 tty1     00:00:01 -bash
root      2031     1  0 13:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/vsftpd
root      2055     2  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 [flush-3:0]
root      2130     1  0 13:55 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2133  2130  0 13:55 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2134  2130  0 13:55 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2135  2130  0 13:55 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2136  2130  0 13:55 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2137  2130  0 13:55 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root      2203     1  0 13:56 ?        00:00:00 dhclient3 -e IF_METRIC=100 -pf /var/run/dhclient.eth0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp3/dhclient.eth0.leases eth0
root      2223     1  0 13:56 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root      3083   266  0 13:58 ?        00:00:00 udevd --daemon
www-data  3202  2130  0 13:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  3203  2130  0 13:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  3204  2130  0 14:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  3205  2130  0 14:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
alex      3209  1971  0 14:05 tty1     00:00:00 ps -aef
```

Comment: have a look at the services and see if any are unneeded. add in a screenshot of top (maybe it's something obvious)

Comment: On my Ubuntu server running LAMP stack with Mail services I only run around 55 processes. I would run `ps -aef` and comb through each making sure you really need each.

Comment: It's possible (and entirely likely) that you might be running a Ubuntu Desktop that's been stripped down a lot. Before we can help you, as @Rinzwind said a screenshot of top would be useful.

Comment: and please add in what you installed! did you install ubuntu-server or did you install the servers on ubuntu desktop. The latter will have 100+ tasks.

Comment: @jrg I installed ubuntu server directly from the official ubuntu site.

Comment: I installed ubuntu server, and a few other small things (apache2, php5) and that's it.  No gui for me.

Comment: Just curious, did you ask this question because some ISP sold you a horribly crippled Virtual Server with only 100 processes allowed? (happened to me -.-) 100 procs is absolutely normal on a base install

Comment: It was on a local server, so the ISP is Irrevalent

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have ten apache threads running to provide faster multi-threaded response time.

You have six terminals running.

I, personally, don't see anything egregiously wasting process space.

Comment: Nor any processes that would be considered "fat" in the system. I say it's a pretty lean setup, numbers aren't *everything*

Comment: the only odd one out is `mouseemu`. That's used for trackpads and TS says he does not have one. But none of the processes seem to be resource hogs.